# Correct use of Apostrophe and quotes on Codeigniter query

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I have a problem with a query using codeigniter with postgresql.
This is my query

```
if ($_respuesta) {
        $this->db->like("regexp_replace('consulta_respuestas.respuesta','<[^>]*>', '', 'g')", $_respuesta);
    }
```

The problem is there is no error at all, but it supposed to display results, but returns 0, and i noticed that codeigniter change this `'<[^>]*>'` to this `' < [^>]*>'` there a spaces between the apostrophe and less than symbol, how i can fix this particular query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `$this->db->query($your_query);` instead of codeigniter stored procedures.

Comment: thanks for the response, how i can add the variable $respuesta inside the query?

Comment: Concat using dots like `'"something "'.$var.'" something"';`

Comment: thanks man i solved it like that but i have another issue that i will ask in another question

Comment: Glad it worked bro ^^

Comment: thanks, can you take a look to my new question? i think you can help me :)